# Targetting WCF Web Api Message Handler at specific requests

Tags: wcf-web-api

Is it possible to target DelegatingHandlers (message handlers) in WCF Web Api at specific requests (as is possible with an operation handler) or are message handlers global. By that I mean they are called for every request.

Comment: Are you talking about being able to switch the handler for the request once it hits the channel stack?

Comment: no, i'm talking about the handler only applying to some requests. i did get an answer via twitter - use the uri. i was hoping to have an attribute against the resource class/method, but it's not possible to get at the from the message handler as easily as it is for operation handlers. i've got an idea on how to do it, so i will probably end up answering my own question once i get that working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up different configurations and map those configurations to the appropriate routes. So for example:

```cs
var config1 = new HttpConfiguration();
config1.MessageHandlers.Add(typeof(MyMessageHandler));
config1.MessageHandlers.Add(typeof(MyMessageHandler2));

var config2 = new HttpConfiguration();
config2.MessageHandlers.Add(typeof(MyMessageHandler3));
config2.MessageHandlers.Add(typeof(MyMessageHandler4));

RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<ContactService>("api/contacts", config1);
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<InvoiceService>("api/invoices", config2);
```